# Security implications of setting the broadcast flag on a UDP socket

Tags: ip, c, packet, udp

Are there any negative security effects of setting the `SO_BROADCAST` option in a C UDP socket? I'm writing a C program and if I just set the broadcast option to 1 then all IP addresses work as intended, but if I don't set it then only unicast or multicast IP addresses will be accepted by the kernel.

Comment: There is no flag field in the UDP (or even IPv4) header for "broadcast". Which bit or option are you talking about?

Comment: The `SO_BROADCAST` flag for `setsockopt` on a UDP socket in C.

Comment: Ah, I see (in `man 7 ip`), and you've already edited your question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, sending broadcast over UDP protocol is normal. So, there is not problem to use `SO_BROADCAST` in `setsockopt(2)`.

**Disclaimer**: The only thing you SHOULD be aware of is the tiny change of `optval` (in `setsockopt(2)`) between Linux and Solaris/sunOS environment.

snippet code example:

```
  static int fd = -1;
/* Use the SVR4 macros to distinguish between Solaris and SunOS */
#if defined(sun) || defined(__sun) || defined(__SVR4) || defined(__svr4__)
/* Solaris || SunOS */
  char on = '1';
#else /* defined(__linux__) */
  uint32_t on = 1;
#endif
  if ((fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))== -1)
  {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    dbg_err_fputs("Cannot open datagram: \"%s\"", strerror(errno));
#else
    dbg_err_fputs("Cannot open datagram");
#endif
  }


#ifdef SO_BROADCAST
  if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &on, sizeof(on)) == -1)
  {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    dbg_err_fputs("Cannot set brodcast flag in socket optname: \"%s\"", strerror(errno));
#else
    dbg_err_fputs("Cannot set broadcast flag in socket optname");
#endif
  }
#endif /* SO_BROADCAST */
```

If your development platform is a Solaris/sunOS, then you will have to add some flags at the end of the command during compilation: `-lnsl -lsocket`. Depending on the Solaris/SunOS version, the socket will only work if you add the `-lxnet` flag... If error persists: `-lresolv`.